# PHP shell_exec() of Python script causes ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, php, environment-variables

I am running a python file from php using `shell_exec` function.
The python file has the following lines

```
import cv2
print('Hello')
```

and in php

```
<?php
    $command = "python test.py ";
    $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
    $output = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
    echo $output;
?>
```

but it is not working
it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/html/test/test.py", line 1, in import cv2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

i have installed opencv, and it runs properly while running from terminal

i also tried using other php functions like `exec` but nothing works.

when i remove `import cv2` it shows the python output

Comment: have you installed opencv?

Comment: yes, the python code runs properly while running from terminal

Comment: Ok guys i figured out the problem, the problem is with linux file permissions not in the code

Comment: does PHP sanitize the environment of the subprocess? I believe this is not specific to OpenCV and would have happened with any other third party python package. I've adjusted the question's title. -- oh, you got the solution? then you should post an answer.

Comment: i don't have the solution, firstly i thought the problem is in the code but its not... the problem is with some permissions and i don't know what is it

Answer (score 0):

Try and set the enviroment variable to Python with it?

```
    $env = "PYTHONPATH=/path/to/opencv/lib/python3.7/site-packages";
    $command = "($env && $command) 2>&1";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: how to get path to opencv, when i use `locate opencv` the output is /home/.....lib/python3.11/site-packages/opencv_python-***